# Do my tests need to be rewritten when mounting a setup() based Vue2.6 component with data param? Upgrading @vue/composition-api from 0.6.7 to 1.7.1

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, upgrade, vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils

I'm having an exciting upgrade in a vue2 project using `@vue/composition-api` 0.6.7, trying to upgrade to 1.7.1.

Some tests are breaking and I'm noticing a pattern where the tests in question mount a component with the data parameter, as if they're reaching in and manipulating a ref

### Example

```
// MyComponent.vue
<script>
export default defineComponent({

  setup() {
    const showModal = ref(false)
    
    return {showModal}
  }
})
</script>
```

Example test which was working before but now is broken.

```
it('should show the modal when the showModal ref is true', () => {

  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, { 
    data: {
      showModal: true
    }
  });

  expect(wrapper.find('#modal').exists()).toBe(true)
}
```

This makes sense to me that this broke in some ways because data is more of an options api thing and creating a ref is more of a composition-api thing-- probably more solidified as we went to 1.0 in the composition-api. That said, do you think that it should work?

When I rewrite the tests to NOT mount using the `data` prop and test it another way, the tests pass fine.  I was expecting it to work as before and honestly not testing using the `mount({data})`, `wrapper.setData()`, or `wrapper.vm` seems like a better approach. I'm just looking for a confirmation or root cause why it worked before and not now.

Beyond this condensed code sample, I have tests using wrapper.setData({ serverResponse }) to simulate when a network call returns. This similarly breaks when I upgrade this composition-api package.